# How to replace entire URL using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

So far I have

```
messageText1 = Regex.Replace(messageText1, "(www|http|https)*?(com|.co.uk|.org)", "[URL OMITTED]");
```

With only the www, and without the bracks or http or https it works as intended

For example and input of `Hey check out this site, www.google.com, it's really cool` would output `hey check out this site, [URL OMITTED], it's really cool`

But if I put back in the or operators for the start of the URL, it only replaces the `.com` part of the input

Why won't it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(www|http|https)*?(com|.co.uk|.org)
```

means `www` or `http` or `https` 0 to many times immediately followed by `com` `.co.uk` or `.org`.
So it would match for example `httphttphttp.co.uk`

Your intention was probably just to have a `.` before the `*`. Which then means it only looks for `(www|http|https)` once, then it matchs `.` (any character) 0 to many times.

You are also missing the `.` in `.com`. However, if you want to match a literal `.` you need to use `\.`, since a `.` on its own means 'any character'.

With that in mind, the regex I think you were going for is:

```
(www|http|https).*?(\.com|\.co\.uk|\.org)
```

Comment: Great, it works. Will accept the answer in 6 minutes thanks!

Comment: Fantastic, no problem

Answer (score 1):

Your  expression  is missing a `.` somewhere or (possibly better) a `\S+`

```
 (www|http|https)\S*(com|\.co\.uk|\.org)
```

In C#:

```
 Regex.Replace(messageText1, @"(www|http|https)\S*(com|\.co\.uk|\.org)", "[URL OMITTED]");
```

Note: you probably want  to escape the .'s as well.

Comment: With that it's telling me \S is an unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: @ÁppleAssassin11 Probably need to escape the backslash since it's within the string: `"(www|http|https)\\S*(com|.co.uk|.org)"`

Answer (score 1):

This should work better. It will also work for other TLDs that don't end with .com, .co.uk or .org:

```
messageText1 = Regex.Replace(messageText1, @"\b(?:http://|https://|www\.)\S+", "[URL OMITTED]");
```

Comment: \b is not required. \S+ will always stop on a \b point.

Comment: Thanks updated this and so that it works with https

Answer (score 0):

A simple version which i tried is as follows.

messageText1 = Regex.Replace(messageText1, @"(www)?(.)?[a-z]*.(com)", "[URL OMITTED]");

i tried this with

string messageText1 = " Hey check this out, http:\www.google.com,its cool";

string messageText1 = " Hey check this out, www.google.com,its cool";

string messageText1 = " Hey check this out, google.com,its cool";